# Mostrar resultado dentro de uma div sem load na pagina

Tags: javascript, html5

Criei uma tela inicial onde você coloca o valor que você quer que seja exibida a tabuada. Porém ao clicar no botão ele pula para outra tela.. queria que ele exibisse na mesma tela a qual já está estilizada.

Como posso fazer? estou usando document.write...

Código:

```
<div class="calculadora">

    <h1>Digite o número que deseja saber a tabuada :</h1> <input type="text" maxlength="2" id="txtNumero">
    <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>

    <div id="resultado">
    </div>
</div>

<script>



    function calcular() {
        numero = document.getElementById("txtNumero").value;


        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

            document.write(`<br>${numero} X ${i} = ${numero * i} <br>`);
        }

    }

</script>
```

[image: IMAGEM DO CODIGO]

Answer (score 1):

Você não está "pulando" para outra tela, você está sobrescrevendo a existente com `document.write`.

Se você não quer perder o HTML da sua página, crie um elemento como uma `div`, e então anexe o seu texto a esse elemento. Acredito inclusive que no seu código, essa div `resultado` já tenha sido criada para essa finalidade, não?

```
function calcular() {
    var numero = document.getElementById("txtNumero").value;
    var elemResultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
    elemResultado.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        elemResultado.innerHTML += `<br>${numero} X ${i} = ${numero * i} <br>`;
    }
}
```

Comment: agradeço muito  @user140828 deu exatamente como eu queria. 
vou estudar um pouco mais sobre innerHTML. Primeira vez que estou usando o stack overflow e foi muito bom. irei ajudar a comunidade também.

Answer (score 0):

Você não está pulando para outra página note o seu URL é o mesmo. O problema de lógica é que você está usando o metódo `write()` este metódo ele é usado na maioria das vezes para testes e não para projetos como este que você fez, pois se um documento html estiver completamente renderizado pelo navegador e `write()` estiver presente ele irar excluir completamente seu documento. Foi o seu caso você adicionou html na sua página e depois chamou o `white()` e o resulatado ele excluiu seu html. Use este método apenas para pequenos teste para resolver isso criei essa solução simples.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calculadora">
    <h1>Digite o número que deseja saber a tabuada :</h1> <input type="text" maxlength="2" id="txtNumero">
    <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
  </div>
<script>
    function calcular() {
        numero = document.getElementById("txtNumero").value;
        
        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            document.body.appendChild(p);
            p.innerHTML = (`<br>${numero} X ${i} = ${numero * i} <br>`);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Não mudou quase nada apenas fiz com que cada vez que o `for` seja executado ele irar criar um parágrafo e adicionara no `body` e o resultado irar ser implementado no parágrafo :).

Comment: Perfeito Leandro Nascimento, testei aqui e deu certinho também. muito boa a lógica. Agradeço muito. ! vc é fera!

Comment: Vlw, é nois! :)